# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.caucho.vfs.Path

Tags: java, php, liferay

I have created a PHP Liferay Portlet and in portlet.xml I added this class:

```
<portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.php.PHPPortlet</portlet-class>
```

When I deploy the portlet I get this error:

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for nsFileUpload-portletnsFileUpload-portlet
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:127)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:205)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/caucho/vfs/Path
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.getPortletInstance(PortletBagFactory.java:418)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:369)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:124)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.caucho.vfs.Path
```

This means that does not find the class `com.caucho.vfs.Path` that is imported from `ServletContextPath.java` ([Source](http://www.boyunjian.com/javasrc/com.liferay.portal/util-bridges/6.2.0-M5/_/com/liferay/util/bridges/php/ServletContextPath.java)).

How can I solve this problem? I need to import that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `resin-util.jar` to your class path. you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/r/Downloadresinutiljar.htm)