# New PHP Liferay portlet in Eclipse

Tags: php, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to develop a simple PHP portlet for Liferay using Eclipse IDE and latest Liferay SDK installed.

After I create a new "Liferay portlet" I see a JSP project with an "entry file" called "view.jsp".

How can I customize it, choosing for example "index.php"?

This is the default portlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>GSI2</portlet-name>
        <display-name>GSI2</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/view.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>GSI2</title>
            <short-title>GSI2</short-title>
            <keywords>GSI2</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

When I try to change "view.jsp" to "index.php", I get the message `Path /index.php is not accessible by this portlet`

Comment: [***Scripting Language Portlets***](https://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Scripting+languages+to+develop+portlets)

Comment: [***PHP Portlets***](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/PHP+Portlets)

Comment: [***ClassNotFoundException: com.caucho.vfs.Path***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146019/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-caucho-vfs-path)

Comment: Change your `<portlet-class>` to `com.liferay.util.bridges.php.PHPPortlet` and `<name>view-template</name>` to `index.php`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've made that changes but I get:
`[http-bio-8080-exec-51][PHPPortlet:241] Error processing PHP
java.lang.NullPointerException`